# Angular app for mobile and desktop same logic diffrent designs

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm looking for the best way to build an angular 7+ app with components that have the same logic but different views and designs for tablet and desktop.

Thank you!

Comment: It's make you app responsible. See e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp. The key is desing for the less resolution and use mediaQuerys to show when the resolution is greater

Comment: [This](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+make+an+angular+app+responsive) will help you better than any of us can. There's not just one simple answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm looking for a way to use same ts file and different html files and scss files for a component .Is there any thing like that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.